# Settings left column - any chance to make it wider?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm so sorry to bother you on such a silly problem. I'm pretty new to VSCode and quite often I'm just missing some trivial things in the UI.

Particularly, I experience some difficulties with guessing the right endings of the left column texts in the "Settings" page:

[image]

As you see there are lots of "..."-words which, indeed, gives a freedom for imagination for creative people. But I'm not that creative, not sure I feel like guessing.

Is there a way to make it larger (wider)? I would expect to use a regular mouse handler  but there is none.

Also, the "Settings" page doesn't allocate the full width of my 2560 px display:

[image]

If not providing a resizable left column is for some reason the principal position of VSCode developers, this one, being horizontally unconstrained would mitigate the above-mentioned problem at least. So can one make it full-width?

Comment: there is a slitter bar, just move the mouse slowly to the right until it changes to a double horizontal arrow, there is a setting to make it wider on hover so you see it more clearly colored

Comment: No any bars here on Linux Kubuntu 20.04. I double-triple checked it just now, was moving it ve-ery slowly.

Comment: locate the debug circles and just left of it is the splitter bar